# Como fazer uma função para dizer quando um array está vazio?

Tags: javascript, array

Preciso de um função que avise quando um array estiver vazio,

```
function validaCampo(){    
   if(count(dias[])==0)
        {
        alert("O Campo Dias disponíveis é obrigatório!");
        return false;
        }
      else
      return true;
}
```

Comment: Não basta so verificar o length do array?

Comment: Ola Já tentou pegar o lenth 

  if(dias.length <= 1)
        {
        alert("O Campo Dias disponíveis é obrigatório!");
        return false;
        }

Comment: Verdade, eu tava achando que o comando que trazia o tamanho de um array era count, muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O JavaScript não tem `count()`, isso é PHP. Podes usar `.length` assim:

```
if(dias.length == 0){
    // etc
}
```

Se só queres um Booleano podes fazer assim:

```js
function validaCampo() {
  const valido = dias.length > 0;
  if (!valido) alert("O Campo Dias disponíveis é obrigatório!");
  return valido;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Já tem pronta:

```
function validaCampo() {    
   if (dias.length == 0) {
        alert("O Campo Dias disponíveis é obrigatório!");
        return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Validation.js).

[Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

Answer (score 3):

Verifique o `length` do array.

```js
vetor = [];
vetor1 = ['item1'];

validaVetor(vetor);
validaVetor(vetor1);

function validaVetor(vetor){
  if(vetor.length>0){
    console.log("Vetor populado");
  }else{
    console.log("Vetor vazio");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Deu certo dessa forma, muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
function checkArray(arr) {
  return !!arr.length
}
```