# Alertar usuário sobre resposta de JSON com retorno vazio []

Tags: ajax, json, alert

Já estou a mais de 15h direto tentado uma solução simples mas que pra mim é muito difícil, por favor me ajudem! Tenho um código que executa uma consulta e quando a entrada for incorreta o retorno é []
Preciso exibir um alerta de entrada incorreta mas estou desde ontem tentando de tudo e não consegui, me desculpem, sou leigo, mas estou aprendendo. Muito obrigado, segue o código:

function buscarPorCpf(){

```
const cpf = document.getElementById("cpf").value;
const mesAno = buscaMes();
const url = "http://localhost/busca-dados/cpf?codigo="+cpf+"&anoMesReferencia="+mesAno+"&anoMesCompetencia="+mesAno+"&pagina=1";


var ajax = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
if (!ajax) {
  throw new Error('CORS not supported');
}


ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {


    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        console.log(this.responseText);
        let resposta = JSON.parse(this.responseText)[0];
        const valor = resposta.valor;
        const nome = resposta.titular.nome;
        const cpf = resposta.titular.cpfFormatado;
        
        document.getElementById("pcpf").innerHTML = cpf;
        document.getElementById("pessoas").innerHTML = nome;
        document.getElementById("pvalor").innerHTML = valor;

    if (resposta == '[]') {
    alert('Entrada incorreta!');
    }

 }
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite Igor,
Percebi pelo seu código que você está tentando da seguinte forma:

```
if (resposta == '[]') {
alert('Entrada incorreta!');
}
```

O seu erro é que você está comparando resposta com uma string contendo '[]', para validar se o array está vazio basta substituir `if (resposta == '[]')` por `if (resposta.length == 0)`

Caso ainda possua duvidas, segue dois links para ajuda-lo:

[Como fazer um função para dizer quando um array está vazio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236418/como-fazer-um-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-dizer-quando-um-array-est%C3%A1-vazio)

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Boa noite! Muito obrigado por responder minha pergunta Jeoronei, alterei o código e não funcionou, acontece que quando a entrada é inválida a resposta do json não exibe nada além de um [] por isso não estou conseguindo encontrar a solução, estou até agora tentando desde ontem.

Comment: Boa noite Igor,
Acho que entendi seu problema agora, você disse `quando a entrada é inválida a resposta do json não exibe nada além de um []`, isso significa que está ocorrendo na parte `console.log(this.responseText)`. Então ele está apresentando erro porque responseText está vazio e você está tentando acessar a posição [0] dele. Neste caso basta você realizar a validação antes de atribuir. Tente fazer o seguinte teste:
`if (this.responseText.length == 0) {
    alert('Entrada incorreta!');
 }` abaixo do `console.log(this.responseText);`

Comment: Bom dia @Jeoronei Ribinski, muito obrigado por me ajudar, funcionou com o seguinte código `if (this.responseText.length < 3) { alert('Entrada incorreta!');  }`